# Count parent nodes in XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, count, parent

I am trying to count all the parent nodes in a XML Document. I have seen solutions like `.SelectNodes("general/parent").Count` but that is a fixed solution. The problem is that I must do it with a generated XML document. So I don't know the XML structure.

I created an example. Imagine that the following document is generated, without knowing any tag names or information at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general>
    <settings>
        <resolution>1920x1080</resolution>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </settings>
    <data>
        <persons>
            <person>
                <name>Bob</name>
                <age>41</age>
            </person>
            <person>
                <name>Alex</name>
                <age>25</age>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </data>
</general>
```

I want to go through this document and have a result of: 5. As the document has 5 "parents" (general, settings, data, persons, and person). But it doesn't count "resolution", "version", "name" and "age" because they have no childs (are no parents). But once again, keep in mind that the document is generated!

I hope this question is clear enough. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: normally i would say use "//*[count(*)>0]", but you'll have to deal with distinct in your loop. (i.e. Person shows up twice, since both are parents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LinqToXml you could do something like:

```
XDocument.Parse(@"...").Descendants().Where(n => n.Elements().Any()).Select(n => n.Name).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: If I use this solution. The end result is: System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d_81`1[System.Xml.Linq.XName] instead of a number. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's the collection of node names that matches your description. Add a .Count() to the end to calculate the number of nodes. I updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive algorithm, like this one;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace GetMaxXMLDepth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string doc = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<general>
    <settings>
        <resolution>1920x1080</resolution>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </settings>
    <data>
        <persons>
            <person>
                <name>Bob</name>
                <age>41</age>
            </person>
            <person>
                <name>Alex</name>
                <age>25</age>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </data>
</general>";
            var xd = XDocument.Parse(doc);

            int maxDepth = GetMaxChildDepth(xd.Root);
        }

        static int GetMaxChildDepth(XElement element)
        {
            int result = 1;

            //always return 1 as the root node has depth of 1.
            //in addition, return the maximum depth returned by this method called on all the children.
            if (element.HasElements)
                result += element.Elements().Max(p => GetMaxChildDepth(p));

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I appreciate it! I'm not really familiar with XDocument. Could you give an example on how to load in a XML Document from an OpenFileDialog?

Comment: @GuidoVisser The static method `XDocument.Load` will take either a `Stream` or a file path. OpenFileDialog.OpenFile() returns a `Stream`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried the answer. It almost works! :D But is also sees the last tag as a "parent" ex. `<name>Alex</name>` maybe because it sees the InnerText as a child? Only if there is a tag under a tag it needs to count as a parent. Is there a way of achieving that? I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: @GuidoVisser I'm not entirely sure it fulfills your requirements. The algorithm calculates the depth of the most nested child in the document, not the number of elements with children. It just so happens that the two are both 5 in the example document.

Comment: Funny thing is that I needed this as well ^^ The solution is just to take the number and take 1 off. I tested it with various XML documents and that seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help! But just as you said, it's not the real answer to this question, so I can't accept your answer on this thread.

Comment: @GuidoVisser glad it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = ParentNode.SelectNodes(ChildNodesXPath).Count;
```